# If $z=(3+7i)(p+iq)$, where $p,q \in Z-{\{0\}}$ is purely imaginary, then the minimum value for $|z|^2$ is

Tags: complex-numbers

> Options
>
> A) 0
>
> B) 58
>
> C) 3364

I know this question has already been asked on this site, but I have a different problem with it

I did the obvious, and obtained $$3p-7q=0$$

For the minimum value of $|z|^2$, the answer will be $(Im(z))^2$

$$=(3q+7p)^2$$

Putting $q =\frac 37 p$

$$=(\frac 97 p +7p)^2$$
$$=p^2(\frac{58}{7})^2$$

Since there are no restrictions on $p$ (other than that it cannot be 0), I could put value as $\frac{7}{\sqrt {58}}$ to get $58$ as the answer

Now, the right answer is $3364$, and I know all the process behind it, but can I get an explanation for this contradiction?

Comment: You assumed $p$ to be an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are restrictions. Notice that they belong to $Z$, the family of INTEGERS. That's why it must be $58^2$.

Comment: Well, I though $Z$ meant complex numbers. I used to the idea of $I$ being an integer, so that may have caused that problem.

Comment: No, no!! $\mathbb{C}$ is the family of complex numbers. learning moment :) Q is rational, and N is natural

Answer (score 2):

For $3p-7q=0$ and $p$ and $q$ to both be integers, we need that $7$ divides $p$. So, we can write $p=7m$ for some (nonzero) integer $m$, and then
$$|z|^2=58^2m^2.$$